# How to limit scroll offset of ListView or ScrollView

Tags: flutter

I want my **ListView**/**ScrollView** to have a limited scroll offset.

Example: I want my listView can not scroll to offset 100. 99 is maximum offset my ListView can reach out.

Comment: whats the goal in limiting the scroll offset? you dont want to show some items in your `Listview` or what? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want pin column to top of ListView when user scroll down.

Comment: I have nested listView in a listView. So I want to limit scroll offset of parent ListView. My goal is pin column of parent listView to top.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you mean by that